# Moving woocommerce to subdomain

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, subdomain

I am trying to move woocommerce on my wordpress site to a a subdomain - includes shop, cart, account etc. Does anyone have any resrouces on this?

Comment: This is just to broad for the question/answer style of StackOverflow. Please specify what you have done and what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a fresh WordPress in subdomain and then install woocommerce  on it. select shop page as home page from setting.

It is not a batter way to separate eCommerce and CMS but you can do this in case of situation.

Answer (score 0):

Still believe there must be a less hacky way, but:

1. point subdomain to the same folder on your hosting
2. in settings->permalinks select everything connected to the shop to be under shop/ in URL:

   - Product category base : shop/product-category
   - Product tag base : shop/product-tag
   - Product attribute base : shop/attributes ...
   - Product permalinks to Shop base or Shop base with category
3. install [Multiple Domain Mapping on single site](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-domain-mapping-on-single-site/) simple plugin
4. (Tools > Multidomain) Map:

   - sub.domain.com to /shop
   - sub.domain.com/cart to /cart (makes exception to the first rule)
   - sub.domain.com/checkout to /checkout (makes exception to the first rule)
   - sub.domain.com/my-account to /my-account (makes exception to the first rule)

The URLs are then duplicite to the original ones but when accessing the subdomain, the permalinks get right and point to the subdomain URLs.